# Symfony 3.4. overwrite class Symfony\Component\Form

Tags: forms, symfony, bundle

i need to overwrite the function "public function submit($submittedData, $clearMissing = true)" in Symfony\Component\Form.

I can overwrite the "RequestHandlerInterface" but not the form component.

Background: There is a problem with choiceTypes if you submit with Patch-Method ([github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17799](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17799)). So i want to insert this line into the submit function:

```
$clearMissing = $this->getConfig()->getOption('expanded', false) ?: $clearMissing;
```

Comment: Hello, why did you need to override the `submit` function?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, you can't.  All if the instance variables are private so an overridden class could not do much anyways.  Plus the form flow is extremely byzantine and it will drive you crazy trying to understand it.  As @GrenierJ has asked, consider describing what you want to do and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: The issue you linked to is four years old and still open.  Pretty clear that there is not much interest from the Symfony folks.  Even if you could somehow extend the class, I don't know of any practical way to have the form system use your class.  What you might try is copying the entire class to something like my_project/symfony and then tweaking the autoload stuff so your modified class comes first.  Have not tried it myself but it might work.  Or it might not. Given the amount of time the issue has basically been ignored, I would try a different approach completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the Form class directly as suggested here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17799#issuecomment-184473725

---

The only problem is: How to make this change permanent for you project?

I ended up creating a patch for the form class. On Linux and supposing you are using git it works something like this:

1. Open a terminal in your project root directory
2. Add the form class to your git repository

   ```
   git add vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
   ```
3. Patch the form class as described above
4. Create a patch

   ```
   git diff > form.patch
   ```
5. Remove the form class from you git repository

   ```
   git rm --cached vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
   ```
6. Somehow incorporate the patch in your project update process. For my project I wrote a small script that runs after every `composer install` or `composer update`.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # apply form component patch to fix HTTP PATCH issue with ChoiceType
   # run after composer install/update
   patch -p1 -N -r /dev/null < form.patch
   ```

The options for the patch command are chosen such that there will be no interaction or other side effects in case the patch was already applied.

---

*form.patch* itself looks something like this:

```
diff --git a/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php b/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
index 67fd234f..27ed9e81 100644
--- a/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
+++ b/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
@@ -553,6 +553,10 @@ class Form implements \IteratorAggregate, FormInterface
                 $submittedData = $event->getData();
             }

+            // HTTP PATCH fix for ChoiceType
+            // https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17799#issuecomment-184473725
+            $clearMissing = $this->getConfig()->getOption('expanded', false) ?: $clearMissing;
+
             // Check whether the form is compound.
             // This check is preferable over checking the number of children,
             // since forms without children may also be compound.
```